# Making select option disable within a map in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a site where users can create events and sell as many ticket types (early bird, general admission etc.) as they like when creating the events.

I'm working on the create event page.

Each time a user creates a new ticket type a function is triggered that pushes a new object to an array in state.

I am then mapping through this array to render the below code for each ticket type.

```
{
  this.state.userEvent.tickets.map((e, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i}>
        Ticket Number {i}:
        <label>
          Ticket Type:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.userEvent.tickets[i].ticketType}
            onChange={event => this.changeTicketDetails(event, "ticketType", i)}
            placeholder="Early Bird, General Admission..."
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          {`Price (${this.state.userEvent.currency})`}
          <input
            type="number"
            value={this.state.userEvent.tickets[i].price}
            onChange={event => this.changeTicketDetails(event, "price", i)}
            placeholder="10"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Number of Tickets
          <input
            type="number"
            value={this.state.userEvent.tickets[i].numberOfTickets}
            onChange={event =>
              this.changeTicketDetails(event, "numberOfTickets", i)
            }
            placeholder="100"
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Start Selling:
          <select
            required
            value={this.state.userEvent.tickets[i].startSelling}
            onChange={event =>
              this.changeTicketDetails(event, "startSelling", i)
            }
          >
            <option value="now">Now</option>
            <option value="specific">Specific Date & Time</option>
            <option value="whenPreviousSoldOut" disabled={(i = 0)}>
              When Previous Tickets Are Sold Out
            </option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <button>Remove</button>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

The final piece of the code sends to state the time when the user wants each ticket to start selling. I want to disable (or hide) the option *'when previous tickets are sold out'*. I am trying to do this by making disabled equal to zero using i from the map to identify the first ticket.

When Previous Tickets Are Sold Out

This won't work and I don't understand why. It also doesn't work when I type out the ternary in full

`{i=0 ? true: false}`

For some reason it appears not to recognize the value of i within the option.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` assigns a value, whereas `==` and `===` compares values.

Did you try `{i === 0 ? true : false}`